# Using refs with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference

I have a problem with ref and conditional rendering. 
I would like to focus an input tag when I click on a button tag. 
Basically, I have this simplified code.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  textInput
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {isEditing: false}
    this.textInput = React.createRef()
  }

    onClick = () => {
        this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing})
        this.textInput.current.focus();
    }
  render () {
    let edit = this.state.isEditing ?
        (<input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />)
        : ""
    return (
      <div>
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>lorem </button>
            {edit}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the button, the input tag is displayed but the ref `textInput` is still set to `null`. Thus I can't focus the input.

I found some workaround like:

- set `autoFocus` property in the input tag
- hide the input tag with css when `isEditing == false`

But actually it is a very basic pattern and I would like to know if there is a clean solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Change this:

```
this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing})
this.textInput.current.focus();
```

to this:

```
this.setState(previousState => ({isEditing: !previousState.isEditing}), () => {
    this.textInput.current.focus();    
});
```

---

### Update: Functional Components / Hooks

It's been asked in the comments how to do this with `useState` and functional components. [Rafał Guźniczak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620210/115049) explains it, but I wanted to provide a bit more explanation and a runnable example.

You still don't want to read state immediately after setting it, but instead of using a second argument callback to `setState`, you need to run some code after the state is updated and the component has re-rendered. How do we do that?

The answer is `useEffect`. The purpose of effects are to synchronize external "things" (for example: imperative DOM things like focus) with React state:

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function App(props) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const textInputRef = useRef(null);

  const toggleEditing = () => setIsEditing(val => !val);

  // whenever isEditing gets set to true, focus the textbox
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditing && textInputRef.current) {
      textInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isEditing, textInputRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleEditing}>lorem </button>
      {isEditing && <input type="text" ref={textInputRef} />}
    </div>
  );
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

### Details:

You're running into a common problem many people run into with React, which is the assumption that setting state is synchronous. It's not. When you call setState, you're *requesting* that React update the state. The actual state update happens later. This means that immediately after the `setState` call, the `edit` element hasn't been created or rendered yet, so the ref points to `null`.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

Comment: Added a bit more detail 

Comment: Got it, I didn't know that we can pass a function as an argument of `setState`

Comment: Yeah, it's usually not the way that most docs introduce `setState`, unfortunately. IMO the API should have _only_ supported the two-function form, and probably should've been called `setStateAsync`, but unfortunately it's a bit late for that :(

Comment: @rossipedia, while your approach is still fine, I would suggest using the functional `setState()` here since the new state depends on the previous one. This is also recommended approach by the official docs.

Comment: hey nice job, how to get this with useState?

Comment: how to achieve this in functional components ?

Comment: simple way is, async function.
```async () => {
  await setState();
  ref.current.focus();
}```

Comment: `setState()` is not an `async` function and cannot be awaited.

Answer (score 4):

Thank a lot for your answer @rossipedia. I was wondering if I can do it with hooks.

And apparently you can't pass second parameter to useState setter as in setState. But you can use useEffect like this (note second parameter in useEffect):

```
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditing) {
        textInput.current.focus();
    }
}, [isEditing]);

const handleClick = () => setIsEditing(isEditing);
```

And it worked! ;)

Source: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback/